# Is logical address space same as secondary memory?

Tags: operating-system

I'm studying paging and I can't understand the concept of logical address. When I say that the CPU gives the logical address of a program do I mean to say that the CPU gives the address in the secondary memory where the program is stored?

Comment: how does your book explain "logical address"?

Comment: also what do you mean by "secondary memory"?

Answer (score 0):

A logical address space is one where "logical addresses" are mapped to "physical addresses." This is a prerequisite for virtual memory. Unfortunately, many sources of documentation conflate the terms virtual memory and logical memory.

On a computer system, physical memory is arranged in page frames numbered 0...N.
Each process has a logical address space consisting of pages numbered 0...M.

Process A has a logical page 1, process B has a logical page 1, but the normally are normally mapped to different physical page frames.

This mapping is defined by set of page tables.

> When I say that the CPU gives the logical address of a program do I mean to say that the CPU gives the address in the secondary memory where the program is stored?

NO!!!!!!!! The logical address maps to a physical address using page tables.

HOWEVER, a logical address may not be mapped into the process address space. In that case, accessing such an address causes an exception. AND, in a virtual memory system, a logical address may be mapped to the process address space but not have a mapping to a physical address. In that case, accessing the logical address causes an exception (a page fault) and the operating system has to load the page from secondary storage (ie disk) into memory.